# How do I use Jsoup to parse html for text?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

How do I use the Jsoup parsing library to parse html files such that Tags should have the same effect as whitespace?

for eg.

If I parse the below string using Jsoup parse function

```
word<br>one<br>is<br>one<br>word
```

I should get

```
word one is one word
```

rather than

```
wordoneisoneword
```

Comment: Jsoup is a parser, not a printer, so when you've got the wrong result at printing, it seems most likely an error in your printing algorithm rather then the parsing. Also, please post your code so far.

Comment: You can do some basic output, eg. text / string or html source. But if you need further formatting, you have implement it yourself.

Comment: As seen in ollo's answer, your desired behavior is what you get by default, so the bug is somewhere in your code.  To help you further, we need to see that code.

Answer (score 1):

Please see here:

```
final String html = "word<br>one<br>is<br>one<br>word";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

String output = doc.text();

System.out.println(output);
```

**Output:**

```
word one is one word
```