# write to docx with Apache POI and enriched text (HTML)

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

i'm writing a docx with apache poi and i have enriched text like `"<p>This is a Paragraph with <strong>enriched text</strong>.</p>"`. But i need that the Word document keep the style like the "strong".

Comment: `Word` cannot interpret `HTML` by default. And `apache poi` does not provide `HTML` to `Office Open XML` conversion per default. So you need programming that your own. Parsing the `HTML` and then setting bold for new created text runs using [XWPFRun.setBold](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#setBold-boolean-).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54268485/how-to-set-define-different-styles-for-the-same-paragraph/54275245#54275245.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have to create bold/italic/underlined texts, then checking the tags like strong yourself and using the build in Apache POI functions setBold/setItalic on the run Class can be an option. If more complex HTML structures like with breaks and lists are also included, then a better option would be to use the JSOUP library in combination with Apache POI. I have good experience with this library in combination with Apache POI.

Simple example:
[How do I use Jsoup to parse html for text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087855/how-do-i-use-jsoup-to-parse-html-for-text)